# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{a}{a^2+bc+4} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for $a,b,c>0$ with $a+b+c=6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove that for $a, b, c > 0$ where $a + b + c = 6$, the following inequality holds:
> $$ \frac{a}{a^2+bc+4} + \frac{b}{b^2+ca+4} + \frac{c}{c^2+ab+4} \leq \frac{1}{2}. $$

From the AM-GM inequality, we find that $ abc \leq 8 $. I attempted to express the first denominator as $(6-b-c)^2+bc+4 = (b+c)^2 - 12(b+c) + bc + 40$. Substituting every $a$ in the inequality with $6-b-c$, the calculations seemed too complicated. I also explored exploiting monotonicity after achieving a common denominator for each fraction.

Comment: math.enthusiast9, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

By AM-GM $a^2+4\ge 4a.$ It implies $$a^2+bc+4\ge 4a+bc \iff \frac{a}{a^2+bc+4}\le \frac{a}{4a+bc}.$$

And we'll prove stronger inequality$$\frac{a}{4a+bc}+\frac{b}{4b+ca}+\frac{c}{4c+ab}\le \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\iff \frac{4a+bc-bc}{4a+bc}+\frac{4b+ca-ca}{4b+ca}+\frac{4c+ab-ab}{4c+ab}\le 2
$$
or$$\frac{bc}{4a+bc}+\frac{ca}{4b+ca}+\frac{ab}{4c+ab}\ge 1.$$
*Notice.* Equality holds iff $a=b=c=2,$ also for $a=b=3,c=0$ and its permutations.

Now, using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{bc}{4a+bc}\ge \frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{12abc+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+(ab)^2}=\frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{2abc(a+b+c)+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+(ab)^2}= 1.$$
Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=2.$

Comment: How does the first inequality found from AM-GM imply the second inequality?

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: How does proving this $$\frac{bc}{4a+bc}+\frac{ca}{4b+ca}+\frac{ab}{4c+ab}\ge 1.$$ (2) proves the first inequality. That’s the part I don’t understand. How did you get (2)?

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 It's equivalence. I added something.